# How trouble with understanding what's being asked on my Taylor Series question?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm currently studying a practice exam for Calc II when I ran into a question that I don't understand. I'm not exactly looking for a solution; rather, a logical guide that I could use to understand what's being asked and some of the steps I can take to achieve the solution.

Here it is:

Suppose the Taylor series for a function f(x) is given by: $$ f(x) = 4 - x + 5x^2 +6x^3-x^4+x^6+...$$

Compute the first four terms of the Taylor Series for $f ''(x^2)$

Is it asking for me to convert $f(x)$ into a general series form and take its double derivative then plug in $x^2$ for $x$?

Here is the solution:
$$f''(x^2) = 10+36x^2-12x^4+30x^8$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's exactly what is asked. Calculate first $f''(x)$, then plug in $x^2$

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x)=-1+10x+18x^2-4x^3+6x^5\dots$

$f''(x)=10+36x-12x^2+30x^4\dots$

$f''(x^2)=10+36x^2-12x^4+30x^8\dots$